# In Matlab how can I exchange the horizontal and vertical axes of an existing plot

Tags: matlab, plot, axes

Suppose I have vectors x and y, I know I can do `plot(x,y)` or `plot(y,x)` to achieve what I want. However, my question is specifically: If I have a plot already created in a figure as `plot(x,y)`, how can I programmatically exchange the horizontal and vertical axes so that effectively I am saying `plot(y,x)`?

Comment: can you please share where does it practically needs to do? it seems to be quiet interesting though you have both the vectors ready in your hand...

Comment: Are you saying that you no longer have `x` and `y` in memory?

Comment: @noufal I am using a GUI of which I have limited control (I am not allowed to fundamentally alter its structure although I can add on to it). The GUI spits out the plot with the axes arranged in a particular way of which I need the opposite. Since I have limited control over the GUI itself this is the only option...

Comment: @dan Yes, I do have them in memory.

Comment: If they are in memory then why not just go `plot(y,x)`?

Comment: @IsopycnalOscillation fine... I didn't think about such a case. . .

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Interesting question +1. The following example shows how to exchange the `x` and `y` axes of the current figure:

```
X = (1:100)'; %# Create x axis data
Y = randn(100, 1); %# Create y axis data
plot(X, Y); %# Plot the data
view(-90, 90) %# Swap the axes
set(gca, 'ydir', 'reverse'); %# Reverse the y-axis (Optional step)
```

Also, a relevant link to Matlab Central is [here](http://www.mathworks.com.au/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/265851).